# use events after loading script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two events which use functions from script. How to start use this functions only after loading script?

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.js"></script> 
    <script>
        var settings = {
            utilsScript: "../lib/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js",
            initialCountry: "auto",
            geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
                $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function () { }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                    var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                    callback(countryCode);
                });
            }
        };
        $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput(settings);
        $("#viber").intlTelInput(settings);

        $("#phoneNumber").on('input', function (e) {
            var intlNumber = $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput("getNumber");
            $("#viber").intlTelInput("setNumber", intlNumber);
        });
        $("#phoneNumber").on("countrychange", function (e, countryData) {
            $("#viber").intlTelInput("setCountry", countryData.iso2);
        });
</script>
```

in google chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function
```

Comment: so where is the ploblem , Why you dont try document ready ?

Comment: try `$(window).load(function() { /* your code */ });` load event is executed when all scripts and images are loaded.

Comment: You are already binding the "intlTelInput" on the phoneNumber after your "intlTelInput.js" script has loaded. Provide a bit more info of your problem. What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: in google chrome console:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function

Comment: your script ~/lib/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.js is probably not extending Jquery as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm located script in Scripts section and it solve the problem.

```
@section Scripts {
        <script src="~/lib/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var settings = {
                    utilsScript: "../lib/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js",
                    initialCountry: "auto",
                    geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
                        $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function () { }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                            callback(countryCode);
                        });
                    }
                };
                $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput(settings);
                $("#viber").intlTelInput(settings);

                $("#phoneNumber").on('input', function (e) {
                    var intlNumber = $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput("getNumber");
                    $("#viber").intlTelInput("setNumber", intlNumber);
                });
                $("#phoneNumber").on("countrychange", function (e, countryData) {
                    $("#viber").intlTelInput("setCountry", countryData.iso2);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$(document).ready(function(){})`

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/intl-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.js"></script> 
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  
        var settings = {
            utilsScript: "../lib/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js",
            initialCountry: "auto",
            geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
                $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function () { }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                    var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                    callback(countryCode);
                });
            }
        };
        $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput(settings);
        $("#viber").intlTelInput(settings);

        $("#phoneNumber").on('input', function (e) {
            var intlNumber = $("#phoneNumber").intlTelInput("getNumber");
            $("#viber").intlTelInput("setNumber", intlNumber);
        });
        $("#phoneNumber").on("countrychange", function (e, countryData) {
            $("#viber").intlTelInput("setCountry", countryData.iso2);
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: Are you load this script through ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include "intlTelInput-jquery.min.js" from the library under jquery. It solved my problem.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/intlTelInput-jquery.min.js"></script>
```